# Singular linked list like "Too many lists" example but without pointer to head

Tags: rust

I have tried the examples in [Learn Rust with Entirely Too Many LInked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html#learn-rust-with-entirely-too-many-linked-lists), but I would like to make a linked list structure without a dedicated struct to point to the head of the list.

In the `pop()` function, since I only have a mutable reference to the node, so I "cannot move out of borrowed content". Is there a way to take out the node with only mutable reference or ownership is the requirement?

I have tried to use `mem::replace()`, but it's not for removing elements. Also the replacement on initializing a new node is pretty weird. Is there a more elegant way of writing a linked list without head pointer?

```rust
use std::mem;
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

pub struct Node<T> {
    val: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T:Copy> Node<T> {
    fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Node { 
            val: val,
            next: None,
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, val: T) {
        let mut new_node = Node {
            val: val,
            next: Some(Box::new(mem::replace(self, Node::new(val)))),
        };
        self = &mut new_node;
    }

    pub fn pop(mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let val = self.val;
        self = *self.next.unwrap();
        Some(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your post to be more explicit about what I think you want (to make a linked list without a `struct List`, only `Node`s). Please check over it and make sure you agree with my edits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the `pop` function to do, though. Your data structure *can't* represent an empty list! What should `list.pop()` do when `list` only contains one element?

Comment: You might want to have a look at something like [`typed_arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/)

Comment: @trentcl I do consider the problem of not able to represent empty list, since in C we can just use a pointer to NULL to indicate, so using a node struct might be enough for C implementation.
However, since Leetcode's linked-list is defined in the "C" style, I am not sure if this is a valid or common idea in rust, or it just a malformed linked-list struct ?

Comment: And yes, not able to represent a empty list also lead to the undefined behavior of popping out a list with only one element...

Comment: But `Node` isn't a pointer, it's just... a node. Structs can't be NULL, even in C. That's more or less the point of the `List` struct. The leetcode example, whatever it is, must be defined differently.